# Creating a unique filename (hash) for user uploaded images

Tags: web-applications, amazon-s3, filenames

I have a web application that allows users to upload images. I store the images in an S3 bucket and give them all filenames that are essentially the result of MD5(session_id + unix_timestamp). Are there any pitfalls of this method for creating unique image filenames?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would consider storing the files with some sort of folder format, as many UI based S3 clients will work much better if there is not 200,000 files in one folder. Also it would not hurt to also add the correct extension and mime type to the uploaded files. That way - if you decide to serve them directly from S3 to a web page, etc - they will be ready to go.

2012/2/6gtbb88uytgfrses4.png

Also you could put the dimensions in the name...

2012/2/6gtbb88uytgfrses4_600x800_.png

Comment: good point about S3 clients not working well with a large number of files in a single directory. Sub-dividing into different directories seems like the way to go.

Comment: how to let s3 let you dynamically generate new directories on upload?  I cannot find the bucket policy for this.

Comment: There are no directories in reality, so you just set the filename on the upload to be the entire path.

Comment: To prevent collisions risk, append a unique_id _after_ the hash

Answer (score 4):

From a uniqueness standpoint, you should be safe. Collisions are not likely (although possible) to occur when using MD5.

But, if you want to provide users with the download of this files, I assume you are storing the original file names elsewhere (database or similar). Is that right? If that is right, you might as well store the session ID and timestamp on the same place, and just go ahead with a GUID for the file name (instead of providing them to your MD5 hash function), which would be safer from a collision standpoint.

Comment: You will not get a collision with MD5.

Comment: @TomAndersen really? I would not be so sure. It is not likely, and I don't think most practical applications of MD5 are threatened by collisions, but it is indeed possible.

Comment: Its only possible for an attack situation, even then its hard. The size of the hash space is not something that can be imagined.

Comment: To prevent collisions risks, append a unique_id _after_ the hash